# passing an ip address as a parameter into a python script template

Tags: azure-devops

I have the following python script with an Azure DevOps pipeline template:

```
# File: templates/clone-docker-volume.yml

parameters:
  sourceVolume: ''
  targetVolume: ''
  pfaEndpoint: ''

steps:
- task: PythonScript@0
  inputs:
    scriptSource: 'inline'
    script: |
      #!/usr/bin/env python3
      import urllib3
      urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
      fa = myfunc(target="${{ parameters.pfaEndpoint }}")
```

When I hard code the ip address calls to the script in the template work as expected, when I change the template such that the ip address is parameterized, I get an error with the following:

HTTPSConnectionPool(host='$(pfaendpoint)', port=443)

I'm invoking the script in the template as follows:

```
- template: templates/python-template.yml  
    parameters:
      pfaEndpoint:  '$(pfaEndpoint)'
```

I suspect this is the problem that is causing the ip address used in the script to appear as '$(pfaEndpoint)'. Can someone please advise how I resolve this such that the ip address is correctly passed into the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can only use that syntax `${{ parameters.something }}` if its a single "thing", you cannot embed it into a string. for that you have to use `format` operator:

```
script: |
  ${{ format('#!/usr/bin/env python3
      import urllib3
      urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
      fa = myfunc(target="{0}")', parameters.pfaEndpoint) }}
```

if you need 2 parameters use this:

```
   ${{ format('{0} {1}', parameters.one, parameters.two) }}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#format

Comment: If myFunc takes more than one parameter, do I use something like:

fa = myfunc(target="{0}", parameters.pfaEndpoint, param2="{0}", parameters.param2) }}

Comment: updated the answer, just use it like you would normally use a format operator in c# more or less

Comment: Thanks for the information, this has fixed my problem, I've marked it as the answer.